# Keyboard does not show up for a text field when running in the simulator

Tags: uitextfield, ios-simulator

When building just a text field I get the following error:

> Controlling The Keyboard[15279:14198101] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.

How can I get rid of that or at least get my simulator iPhone 6s to run the code and show the keyboard?

Comment: Hey forget about that, it was as simple as to go to Simulator Menu, HArdware, and select Keyboard --> Toogle Keyboard Software

Answer (score 3):

You can toggle Software Keyboard in this way:

[image]

Comment: Additionally, you can use the hotkey `CMD+k` to toggle between the hardware and the software keybord.